# Creating a Caesar Cipher Method

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, caesar-cipher

So I need to get the Caesar Cipher code in smalltalk and create a method and use it so I can do the following test on it

```
|aString|
aString:=Caesar new encrypt: 'CAESAR'.
Transcript show: aString.
```

I already have the class made. But I need to make the method of it.

I found this but how can I make a method out of this so I can all the above code in playground.

```
| i c strCipherText strText iShiftValue iShift |

strText := 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.
iShiftValue := 3.

strCipherText := ''.
iShift := iShiftValue \\ 26.

i := 1.
[ i <= (strText size) ]
whileTrue: [
  c := (strText at: i) asUppercase.

  ( ( c >= $A) & ( c <= $Z ) )
  ifTrue: [

    ((c asciiValue) + iShift > $Z asciiValue)
    ifTrue: [
      strCipherText := strCipherText, (((c asciiValue) + iShift - 26)
                      asCharacter asString).
    ]
    ifFalse: [
      strCipherText := strCipherText, (((c asciiValue) + iShift)
                      asCharacter asString).
    ].

  ]
  ifFalse: [
    strCipherText := strCipherText, ' '.
  ].

  i := i + 1.
].

Transcript show: strCipherText.
Transcript cr.
```

So to make thing clear, I need to make a method using the Caesar Cipher code and use the "aString" code at the beginning and test it with that. I have this code above but this has already text in it and can't be put into the method.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Of course you can put it into a method. Simply replace `strText` with a method argument. For example: the method might be called `#myCaesorCodeOf:` and take one argument called `aString`.

Comment: @MaxLeske I'm new to using pharo and small talk so I dont really know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Max said in his comment the code above can be put in a method. The only missing part is a first line with the selector and the formal argument:

```
caesarCipherOf: strText
  <insert the code here>
```

Another good suggestion by Max is to call the argument `aString` rather than `strText` because that's more aligned with how Smalltalkers name things.

But now let's take a look at the source code itself:

1. The comparison `c >= $A & (c <= $Z)` means `c isLetter`.
2. The conditional calculation of the next character means that we want to shift-rotate `c` by moving it `3` characters to the right, wrapping it around if it gets beyond `$Z`. This can be easily expressed as:

   ```
   (c codePoint - 64 + 3 \\ 26 + 64) asCharacter
   ```

   where `64 = $A codePoint - 1`, is the offset between `$A` and any given uppercase character `c`. Note also that I've replaced `asciiValue` with `codePoint`.

With these two observations the method can be re-written as

```
    caesarCipherOf: aString
      ^aString collect: [:c |
        c isLetter
          ifTrue: [(c asUppercase codePoint - 64 + 3 \\ 26 + 64) asCharacter]
          ifFalse: [$ ]]
```

This is not only shorter, it is more efficient because it avoids creating **two** new instances of `String` at every character. Specifically, any expression of the form

```
string := string , <character> asString
```

creates two `Strings`: one as the result of sending `#asString`, another as the result of sending the concatenation message `#,`. Instead, `#collect:` creates only one instance, the one that the method returns.